# How to make start jquery .animation from center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".active" ).animate({width: "100%"}, 500);
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="active"></div>
```

With the styles:

```
.active {
    background: #1f679b;
    height: 4px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

How can I do the animation start at the center instead of starting on the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply change

```
margin-top: -4px
```

into

```
margin: -4px auto 0 auto;
```

The resulting effect is a div that grows but during the animation it's always centered due to the left and right margin set to `auto`. No need to change the animation properties

---

**Codepen example**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IpFxn

Answer (score 2):

Start with a 50% margin:

```
.active {
    background: #1f679b;
    height: 4px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

and animate that to 0:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".active" ).animate({
        width: "100%", 
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qkh6n/